# How to convert from string to number in Oracle using TO_NUMBER function with fixed decimal point char?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, number-formatting

I need to convert in procedure from `string` to `decimal` with fixed decimal separator `.` independant on culture settings. Next, I know decimal number is limited just with 6 decimal places after `.` and there is no limitiation on number of digits before `.`. Using Oracle documentation and its examples for format strings I have now just this solution:

```
v_number := TO_NUMBER(v_string, '9999999999999999999999999999999999D999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''. ''');
```

Number of `9` chars before `D` is maximum number allowed. I find this format string as pretty awful. Is there any better format string for this general conversion or some way to omit second parameter of function? In general I just need to pass to function NLS parameter to tell it i just want to convert with decimal separator `.`, but second parameter is mandatory in that case as well.

Comment: If the number in the string form is always like '9999.99999' why don't you simply use TO_NUMBER()? You want to put the constraint of it having 6 digits after the decimal?

Comment: @cybernate: `to_number(:X)` will parse X in the NLS setting of the session, which might have a different numerical separator than "."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't call the `to_number` function with the third parameter and not the second. I would suggest putting the "ugly" format string in a package constant and forget about it.

You could also use [`dbms_session.set_nls`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sessio.htm#i1010906) to modify your NLS settings and be able to use `to_number` without arguments.

Comment: +1 ... or ,using the same line of thought, you can create your own (packaged) function "our_to_number", and hide the implementation details altogether.

Comment: Probably the most clear solution. Thx for making me sure i'm on the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Handles both comma and period.

```
FUNCTION to_number2(p_num_str VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER AS
BEGIN
  RETURN TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(p_num_str, ',', '.'), '999999999999D999999999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,''');
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IS_NUMBER(P_VAR IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
  P_NUMBER NUMBER := 0;
  RIG VARCHAR2(10) := '';
  FORMAT VARCHAR2(100) := '999999999999D999999999999';
  RES VARCHAR2(100) := '';
BEGIN
  SELECT VALUE INTO RIG 
  FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS';
IF SUBSTR(RIG,1,1) = '.' THEN
 RES := REPLACE(P_VAR,',','.');
ELSE
 RES := REPLACE(P_VAR,'.',',');
END IF;
 P_NUMBER := TO_NUMBER(RES,FORMAT,'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='''||RIG||'''');
 P_NUMBER := ROUND(P_NUMBER,5); --FIVE DIGITS AFTER DECIMAL POINT IS ENOUGH
RETURN P_NUMBER;
EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN RETURN -1;
END;
```

Comment: Could you write your comment in english instead of russian?

Comment: ПЯТЬ ЗНАКОВ ПОСЛЕ ЗАПЯТОЙ ДОСТАТОЧНО = Five decimals are enough.

Answer (score -4):

```
select to_number('   12.5   ') + to_number('   12   ') from dual;
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?